# Разблокировать кнопку при совпадении значений в объявленной переменной

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, autocomplete

Есть поле `input`, с автоподбором значений (города). Данные берутся из `js-файла`, в котором собственно и написан алгоритм. Необходимо отслеживать поле `input`, в которое вносится текст. Успешным результатом, будет считаться разблокировка кнопки, за счёт удаления атрибута `disabled`, при совпадении данных.
Данные должны совпадать с теми, что находятся в переменной `city`. Добавил якорь `checkParams()` к полю, которое необходимо проверять, в итоге получается только проверять наличие любого значения а не совпадение данных..

```js
function checkParams() {
  var name = jQuery('#myInput').val();
  if (name = тутчтотодолжнобыть {
      jQuery('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
      jQuery('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  }
```

[Пример кода](https://jsfiddle.net/Alex45678/e6cbpj49/11/)

Comment: Покажите Вашу разметку, чтобы сказать точно. На вскидку - можете передавать параметр в функцию `function checkParams(param) {` и уже в функции работать с ним.

Comment: @Denis640Kb, [ссылка на скрин](https://ibb.co/PztRspC)

Comment: При вводе значений в поисковую строку, формируются див блоки с разными значениями, вариантами выбора. Когда выбор делается, дивы сворачиваются и значение передается в основной `id="myInput"`

Comment: Если он точно передаётся в `input`, то просто в нём же используйте передачу параметра `<input id="myInput" onkeyup="checkParams(this.value)" type="text">` А в функции берёте это значение через `unction checkParams(param) {`

Comment: @Denis640Kb, Протестировал, в консоли Unexpected token 'this` :(

Comment: Либо где-то допустили ошибку, либо данные не передаются в `input`. Добавил временно пример для демонстрации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="city.js"></script>
<script>
    var city = ["Адыгейск", "Майкоп", "Горно-Алтайск", "Алейск", "Барнаул", "Белокуриха", "Бийск", "Горняк", "Заринск", "Змеиногорск", "Камень-на-Оби", "Новоалтайск", "Рубцовск", "Славгород", "Яровое", "Белогорск", "Благовещенск", "Завитинск", "Зея", "Райчихинск", "Свободный", "Сковородино", "Тында", "Шимановск", "Архангельск", "Вельск", "Каргополь", "Коряжма", "Котлас", "Мезень", "Мирный", "Новодвинск", "Няндома", "Онега", "Северодвинск", "Сольвычегодск", "Шенкурск", "Астрахань", "Ахтубинск", "Знаменск", "Камызяк", "Нариманов", "Харабали", "Агидель", "Баймак", "Белебей", "Белорецк", "Бирск", "Благовещенск", "Давлеканово", "Дюртюли", "Ишимбай", "Кумертау", "Межгорье", "Мелеуз", "Нефтекамск", "Октябрьский", "Салават", "Сибай", "Стерлитамак", "Туймазы", "Уфа", "Учалы", "Янаул", "Алексеевка", "Белгород", "Бирюч", "Валуйки", "Грайворон", "Губкин", "Короча", "Новый Оскол", "Старый Оскол", "Строитель", "Шебекино", "Брянск", "Дятьково", "Жуковка", "Злынка", "Карачев", "Клинцы", "Мглин", "Новозыбков", "Почеп", "Севск", "Сельцо", "Стародуб", "Сураж", "Трубчевск", "Унеча", "Фокино", "Бабушкин", "Гусиноозёрск", "Закаменск", "Кяхта", "Северобайкальск", "Улан-Удэ", "Александров", "Владимир", "Вязники", "Гороховец", "Гусь-Хрустальный", "Камешково", "Карабаново", "Киржач", "Ковров", "Кольчугино", "Костерёво", "Курлово", "Лакинск", "Меленки", "Муром", "Петушки", "Покров", "Радужный", "Собинка", "Струнино", "Судогда", "Суздаль", "Юрьев-Польский", "Волгоград", "Волжский", "Дубовка", "Жирновск", "Калач-на-Дону", "Камышин", "Котельниково", "Котово", "Краснослободск", "Ленинск", "Михайловка", "Николаевск", "Новоаннинский", "Палласовка", "Петров Вал", "Серафимович", "Суровикино", "Урюпинск", "Фролово", "Бабаево", "Белозерск", "Великий Устюг", "Вологда", "Вытегра", "Грязовец", "Кадников", "Кириллов", "Красавино", "Никольск", "Сокол", "Тотьма", "Устюжна", "Харовск", "Череповец", "Бобров", "Богучар", "Борисоглебск", "Бутурлиновка", "Воронеж", "Калач", "Лиски", "Нововоронеж", "Новохопёрск", "Острогожск", "Павловск", "Поворино", "Россошь", "Семилуки", "Эртиль", "Буйнакск", "Дагестанские Огни", "Дербент", "Избербаш", "Каспийск", "Кизилюрт", "Кизляр", "Махачкала", "Хасавюрт", "Южно-Сухокумск", "Биробиджан", "Облучье", "Балей", "Борзя", "Краснокаменск", "Могоча", "Нерчинск", "Петровск-Забайкальский", "Сретенск", "Хилок", "Чита", "Шилка", "Вичуга", "Гаврилов Посад", "Заволжск", "Иваново", "Кинешма", "Комсомольск", "Кохма", "Наволоки", "Плёс", "Приволжск", "Пучеж", "Родники", "Тейково", "Фурманов", "Шуя", "Южа", "Юрьевец", "Карабулак", "Магас", "Малгобек", "Назрань", "Алзамай", "Ангарск", "Байкальск", "Бирюсинск", "Бодайбо", "Братск", "Вихоревка", "Железногорск-Илимский", "Зима", "Иркутск", "Киренск", "Нижнеудинск", "Саянск", "Свирск", "Слюдянка", "Тайшет", "Тулун", "Усолье-Сибирское", "Усть-Илимск", "Усть-Кут", "Черемхово", "Шелехов", "Баксан", "Майский", "Нальчик", "Нарткала", "Прохладный", "Терек", "Тырныауз", "Чегем", "Багратионовск", "Балтийск", "Гвардейск", "Гурьевск", "Гусев", "Зеленоградск", "Калининград", "Краснознаменск", "Ладушкин", "Мамоново", "Неман", "Нестеров", "Озёрск", "Пионерский", "Полесск", "Правдинск", "Светлогорск", "Светлый", "Славск", "Советск", "Черняховск", "Приморск", "Городовиковск", "Лагань", "Элиста", "Балабаново", "Белоусово", "Боровск", "Ермолино", "Жиздра", "Жуков", "Калуга", "Киров", "Козельск", "Кондрово", "Кремёнки", "Людиново", "Малоярославец", "Медынь", "Мещовск", "Мосальск", "Обнинск", "Сосенский", "Спас-Деменск", "Сухиничи", "Таруса", "Юхнов", "Вилючинск", "Елизово", "Петропавловск-Камчатский", "Карачаевск", "Теберда", "Усть-Джегута", "Черкесск", "Беломорск", "Кемь", "Кондопога", "Костомукша", "Лахденпохья", "Медвежьегорск", "Олонец", "Петрозаводск", "Питкяранта", "Пудож", "Сегежа", "Сортавала", "Суоярви", "Анжеро-Судженск", "Белово", "Берёзовский", "Гурьевск", "Калтан", "Кемерово", "Киселёвск", "Ленинск-Кузнецкий", "Мариинск", "Междуреченск", "Мыски", "Новокузнецк", "Осинники", "Полысаево", "Прокопьевск", "Салаир", "Тайга", "Таштагол", "Топки", "Юрга", "Белая Холуница", "Вятские Поляны", "Зуевка", "Киров", "Кирово-Чепецк", "Кирс", "Котельнич", "Луза", "Малмыж", "Мураши", "Нолинск", "Омутнинск", "Орлов", "Слободской", "Советск", "Сосновка", "Уржум", "Яранск", "Воркута", "Вуктыл", "Емва", "Инта", "Микунь", "Печора", "Сосногорск", "Сыктывкар", "Усинск", "Ухта", "Буй", "Волгореченск", "Галич", "Кологрив", "Кострома", "Макарьев", "Мантурово", "Нерехта", "Нея", "Солигалич", "Чухлома", "Шарья", "Абинск", "Анапа", "Апшеронск", "Армавир", "Белореченск", "Геленджик", "Горячий Ключ", "Гулькевичи", "Ейск", "Кореновск", "Краснодар", "Кропоткин", "Крымск", "Курганинск", "Лабинск", "Новокубанск", "Новороссийск", "Приморско-Ахтарск", "Славянск-на-Кубани", "Сочи", "Темрюк", "Тимашёвск", "Тихорецк", "Туапсе", "Усть-Лабинск", "Хадыженск", "Артёмовск", "Ачинск", "Боготол", "Бородино", "Дивногорск", "Дудинка", "Енисейск", "Железногорск", "Заозёрный", "Зеленогорск", "Игарка", "Иланский", "Канск", "Кодинск", "Красноярск", "Лесосибирск", "Минусинск", "Назарово", "Норильск", "Сосновоборск", "Ужур", "Уяр", "Шарыпово", "Далматово", "Катайск", "Курган", "Куртамыш", "Макушино", "Петухово", "Шадринск", "Шумиха", "Щучье", "Дмитриев", "Железногорск", "Курск", "Курчатов", "Льгов", "Обоянь", "Рыльск", "Суджа", "Фатеж", "Щигры", "Бокситогорск", "Волосово", "Волхов", "Всеволожск", "Выборг", "Высоцк", "Гатчина", "Ивангород", "Каменногорск", "Кингисепп", "Кириши", "Кировск", "Коммунар", "Лодейное Поле", "Луга", "Любань", "Никольское", "Новая Ладога", "Отрадное", "Пикалёво", "Подпорожье", "Приморск", "Приозерск", "Светогорск", "Сертолово", "Сланцы", "Сосновый Бор", "Сясьстрой", "Тихвин", "Тосно", "Шлиссельбург", "Грязи", "Данков", "Елец", "Задонск", "Лебедянь", "Липецк", "Усмань", "Чаплыгин", "Магадан", "Сусуман", "Волжск", "Звенигово", "Йошкар-Ола", "Козьмодемьянск", "Ардатов", "Инсар", "Ковылкино", "Краснослободск", "Рузаевка", "Саранск", "Темников", "Москва", "Апрелевка", "Балашиха", "Бронницы", "Верея", "Видное", "Волоколамск", "Воскресенск", "Высоковск", "Голицыно", "Дедовск", "Дзержинский", "Дмитров", "Долгопрудный", "Домодедово", "Дрезна", "Дубна", "Егорьевск", "Железнодорожный", "Жуковский", "Зарайск", "Звенигород", "Ивантеевка", "Истра", "Кашира", "Климовск", "Клин", "Коломна", "Котельники", "Королёв", "Красноармейск", "Красногорск", "Краснозаводск", "Краснознаменск", "Кубинка", "Куровское", "Ликино-Дулёво", "Лобня", "Лосино-Петровский", "Луховицы", "Лыткарино", "Люберцы", "Можайск", "Московский", "Мытищи", "Наро-Фоминск", "Ногинск", "Одинцово", "Ожерелье", "Озёры", "Орехово-Зуево", "Павловский Посад", "Пересвет", "Подольск", "Протвино", "Пушкино", "Пущино", "Раменское", "Реутов", "Рошаль", "Руза", "Сергиев Посад", "Серпухов", "Солнечногорск", "Старая Купавна", "Ступино", "Талдом", "Троицк", "Фрязино", "Химки", "Хотьково", "Черноголовка", "Чехов", "Шатура", "Щёлково", "Щербинка", "Электрогорск", "Электросталь", "Электроугли", "Юбилейный", "Яхрома", "Апатиты", "Гаджиево", "Заозёрск", "Заполярный", "Кандалакша", "Кировск", "Ковдор", "Кола", "Мончегорск", "Мурманск", "Оленегорск", "Островной", "Полярные Зори", "Полярный", "Североморск", "Снежногорск", "Нарьян-Мар", "Арзамас", "Балахна", "Богородск", "Бор", "Ветлуга", "Володарск", "Ворсма", "Выкса", "Горбатов", "Городец", "Дзержинск", "Заволжье", "Княгинино", "Кстово", "Кулебаки", "Лукоянов", "Лысково", "Навашино", "Нижний Новгород", "Павлово", "Первомайск", "Перевоз", "Саров", "Семёнов", "Сергач", "Урень", "Чкаловск", "Шахунья", "Боровичи", "Валдай", "Великий Новгород", "Малая Вишера", "Окуловка", "Пестово", "Сольцы", "Старая Русса", "Холм", "Чудово", "Барабинск", "Бердск", "Болотное", "Искитим", "Карасук", "Каргат", "Куйбышев", "Купино", "Новосибирск", "Обь", "Татарск", "Тогучин", "Черепаново", "Чулым", "Исилькуль", "Калачинск", "Называевск", "Омск", "Тара", "Тюкалинск", "Абдулино", "Бугуруслан", "Бузулук", "Гай", "Кувандык", "Медногорск", "Новотроицк", "Оренбург", "Орск", "Соль-Илецк", "Сорочинск", "Ясный", "Болхов", "Дмитровск", "Ливны", "Малоархангельск", "Мценск", "Новосиль", "Орёл", "Белинский", "Городище", "Заречный", "Каменка", "Кузнецк", "Нижний Ломов", "Никольск", "Пенза", "Сердобск", "Спасск", "Сурск", "Александровск", "Березники", "Верещагино", "Горнозаводск", "Гремячинск", "Губаха", "Добрянка", "Кизел", "Красновишерск", "Краснокамск", "Кудымкар", "Кунгур", "Лысьва", "Нытва", "Оса", "Оханск", "Очёр", "Пермь", "Соликамск", "Усолье", "Чайковский", "Чердынь", "Чёрмоз", "Чернушка", "Чусовой", "Арсеньев", "Артём", "Большой Камень", "Владивосток", "Дальнегорск", "Дальнереченск", "Лесозаводск", "Находка", "Партизанск", "Спасск-Дальний", "Уссурийск", "Фокино", "Великие Луки", "Гдов", "Дно", "Невель", "Новоржев", "Новосокольники", "Опочка", "Остров", "Печоры", "Порхов", "Псков", "Пустошка", "Пыталово", "Себеж", "Азов", "Аксай", "Батайск", "Белая Калитва", "Волгодонск", "Гуково", "Донецк", "Зверево", "Зерноград", "Каменск-Шахтинский", "Константиновск", "Красный Сулин", "Миллерово", "Морозовск", "Новочеркасск", "Новошахтинск", "Пролетарск", "Ростов-на-Дону", "Сальск", "Семикаракорск", "Таганрог", "Цимлянск", "Шахты", "Касимов", "Кораблино", "Михайлов", "Новомичуринск", "Рыбное", "Ряжск", "Рязань", "Сасово", "Скопин", "Спас-Клепики", "Спасск-Рязанский", "Шацк", "Жигулёвск", "Кинель", "Нефтегорск", "Новокуйбышевск", "Октябрьск", "Отрадный", "Похвистнево", "Самара", "Сызрань", "Тольятти", "Чапаевск", "Зеленогорск", "Колпино", "Красное Село", "Кронштадт", "Ломоносов", "Павловск", "Петергоф", "Пушкин", "Санкт-Петербург", "Сестрорецк", "Аркадак", "Аткарск", "Балаково", "Балашов", "Вольск", "Ершов", "Калининск", "Красноармейск", "Красный Кут", "Маркс", "Новоузенск", "Петровск", "Пугачёв", "Ртищево", "Саратов", "Хвалынск", "Шиханы", "Энгельс", "Александровск-Сахалинский", "Анива", "Долинск", "Корсаков", "Курильск", "Макаров", "Невельск", "Оха", "Поронайск", "Северо-Курильск", "Томари", "Углегорск", "Холмск", "Шахтёрск", "Южно-Сахалинск", "Алапаевск", "Арамиль", "Артёмовский", "Асбест", "Берёзовский", "Богданович", "Верхний Тагил", "Верхняя Пышма", "Верхняя Салда", "Верхняя Тура", "Верхотурье", "Волчанск", "Дегтярск", "Екатеринбург", "Заречный", "Ивдель", "Ирбит", "Каменск-Уральский", "Камышлов", "Карпинск", "Качканар", "Кировград", "Краснотурьинск", "Красноуральск", "Красноуфимск", "Кушва", "Лесной", "Михайловск", "Невьянск", "Нижние Серги", "Нижний Тагил", "Нижняя Салда", "Нижняя Тура", "Новая Ляля", "Новоуральск", "Первоуральск", "Полевской", "Ревда", "Реж", "Североуральск", "Серов", "Среднеуральск", "Сухой Лог", "Сысерть", "Тавда", "Талица", "Туринск", "Алагир", "Ардон", "Беслан", "Владикавказ", "Дигора", "Моздок", "Велиж", "Вязьма", "Гагарин", "Демидов", "Десногорск", "Дорогобуж", "Духовщина", "Ельня", "Починок", "Рославль", "Рудня", "Сафоново", "Смоленск", "Сычёвка", "Ярцево", "Благодарный", "Будённовск", "Георгиевск", "Ессентуки", "Железноводск", "Зеленокумск", "Изобильный", "Ипатово", "Кисловодск", "Лермонтов", "Минеральные Воды", "Михайловск", "Невинномысск", "Нефтекумск", "Новоалександровск", "Новопавловск", "Пятигорск", "Светлоград", "Ставрополь", "Жердевка", "Кирсанов", "Котовск", "Мичуринск", "Моршанск", "Рассказово", "Тамбов", "Уварово", "Агрыз", "Азнакаево", "Альметьевск", "Арск", "Бавлы", "Болгар", "Бугульма", "Буинск", "Елабуга", "Заинск", "Зеленодольск", "Казань", "Лаишево", "Лениногорск", "Мамадыш", "Менделеевск", "Мензелинск", "Набережные Челны", "Нижнекамск", "Нурлат", "Тетюши", "Чистополь", "Андреаполь", "Бежецк", "Белый", "Бологое", "Весьегонск", "Вышний Волочёк", "Западная Двина", "Зубцов", "Калязин", "Кашин", "Кимры", "Конаково", "Красный Холм", "Кувшиново", "Лихославль", "Нелидово", "Осташков", "Ржев", "Старица", "Тверь", "Торжок", "Торопец", "Удомля", "Асино", "Кедровый", "Колпашево", "Северск", "Стрежевой", "Томск", "Алексин", "Белёв", "Богородицк", "Болохово", "Венёв", "Донской", "Ефремов", "Кимовск", "Киреевск", "Липки", "Новомосковск", "Плавск", "Суворов", "Тула", "Узловая", "Чекалин", "Щёкино", "Ясногорск", "Советск", "Ак-Довурак", "Кызыл", "Туран", "Чадан", "Шагонар", "Заводоуковск", "Ишим", "Тобольск", "Тюмень", "Ялуторовск", "Воткинск", "Глазов", "Ижевск", "Камбарка", "Можга", "Сарапул", "Барыш", "Димитровград", "Инза", "Новоульяновск", "Сенгилей", "Ульяновск", "Амурск", "Бикин", "Вяземский", "Комсомольск-на-Амуре", "Николаевск-на-Амуре", "Советская Гавань", "Хабаровск", "Абаза", "Абакан", "Саяногорск", "Сорск", "Черногорск", "Белоярский", "Когалым", "Лангепас", "Лянтор", "Мегион", "Нефтеюганск", "Нижневартовск", "Нягань", "Покачи", "Пыть-Ях", "Радужный", "Советский", "Сургут", "Урай", "Ханты-Мансийск", "Югорск", "Аша", "Бакал", "Верхнеуральск", "Верхний Уфалей", "Еманжелинск", "Златоуст", "Карабаш", "Карталы", "Касли", "Катав-Ивановск", "Копейск", "Коркино", "Куса", "Кыштым", "Магнитогорск", "Миасс", "Миньяр", "Нязепетровск", "Озёрск", "Пласт", "Сатка", "Сим", "Снежинск", "Трёхгорный", "Троицк", "Усть-Катав", "Чебаркуль", "Челябинск", "Южноуральск", "Юрюзань", "Аргун", "Грозный", "Гудермес", "Урус-Мартан", "Шали", "Алатырь", "Канаш", "Козловка", "Мариинский Посад", "Новочебоксарск", "Цивильск", "Чебоксары", "Шумерля", "Ядрин", "Анадырь", "Билибино", "Певек", "Алдан", "Верхоянск", "Вилюйск", "Ленск", "Мирный", "Нерюнгри", "Нюрба", "Олёкминск", "Покровск", "Среднеколымск", "Томмот", "Удачный", "Якутск", "Губкинский", "Лабытнанги", "Муравленко", "Надым", "Новый Уренгой", "Ноябрьск", "Салехард", "Тарко-Сале", "Гаврилов-Ям", "Данилов", "Любим", "Мышкин", "Переславль-Залесский", "Пошехонье", "Ростов", "Рыбинск", "Тутаев", "Углич", "Ярославль"];
    function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
        /*the autocomplete function takes two arguments,
        the text field element and an array of possible autocompleted values:*/
        var currentFocus;
        /*execute a function when someone writes in the text field:*/
        inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
            var a, b, i, val = this.value;
            /*close any already open lists of autocompleted values*/
            closeAllLists();
            if (!val) { return false;}
            currentFocus = -1;
            /*create a DIV element that will contain the items (values):*/
            a = document.createElement("DIV");
            a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
            a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
            /*append the DIV element as a child of the autocomplete container:*/
            this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
            /*for each item in the array...*/
            for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                /*check if the item starts with the same letters as the text field value:*/
                if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
                    /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
                    b = document.createElement("DIV");
                    /*make the matching letters bold:*/
                    b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
                    b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
                    /*insert a input field that will hold the current array item's value:*/
                    b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
                    /*execute a function when someone clicks on the item value (DIV element):*/
                    b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                        /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
                        inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
                        /*close the list of autocompleted values,
                        (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
                        closeAllLists();
                    });
                    a.appendChild(b);
                }
            }
        });
        /*execute a function presses a key on the keyboard:*/
        inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
            var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
            if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
            if (e.keyCode == 40) {
                /*If the arrow DOWN key is pressed,
                increase the currentFocus variable:*/
                currentFocus++;
                /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
                addActive(x);
            } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
                /*If the arrow UP key is pressed,
                decrease the currentFocus variable:*/
                currentFocus--;
                /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
                addActive(x);
            } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                /*If the ENTER key is pressed, prevent the form from being submitted,*/
                e.preventDefault();
                if (currentFocus > -1) {
                    /*and simulate a click on the "active" item:*/
                    if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
                }
            }
        });
        function addActive(x) {
            /*a function to classify an item as "active":*/
            if (!x) return false;
            /*start by removing the "active" class on all items:*/
            removeActive(x);
            if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
            if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
            /*add class "autocomplete-active":*/
            x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
        }
        function removeActive(x) {
            /*a function to remove the "active" class from all autocomplete items:*/
            for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
            }
        }
        function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
            /*close all autocomplete lists in the document,
            except the one passed as an argument:*/
            var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
            for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
                    x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        /*execute a function when someone clicks in the document:*/
        document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            closeAllLists(e.target);
        });
    }
</script>
<style>
    * { box-sizing: border-box; }
    body {
        font: 16px Arial;
    }
    .autocomplete {
        /*the container must be positioned relative:*/
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    input {
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    input[type=text] {
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        width: 100%;
    }
    input[type=submit] {
        background-color: DodgerBlue;
        color: #fff;
    }
    .autocomplete-items {
        position: absolute;
        border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
        border-bottom: none;
        border-top: none;
        z-index: 99;
        /*position the autocomplete items to be the same width as the container:*/
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
    .autocomplete-items div {
        padding: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
    }
    .autocomplete-items div:hover {
        /*when hovering an item:*/
        background-color: #e9e9e9;
    }
    .autocomplete-active {
        /*when navigating through the items using the arrow keys:*/
        background-color: DodgerBlue !important;
        color: #ffffff;
    }
</style>
<form autocomplete="off" action="index.html"  target="_blank">
    <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
        <input id="myInput" onKeyUp="checkParams();" type="text" name="myCity" placeholder="Введите название города">
    </div>
    <input id="submit" disabled type="submit">
</form>
<script>
    autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), city);
</script>

<script>
    function checkParams(){
        document.getElementById('submit').style.display = "none"
        let par = document.getElementById('myInputautocomplete-list');
        let auto = par.getElementsByTagName('div');

        for (let i = 0; i < auto.length; i++){
            auto[i].onclick = function () {
                var val = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
                var check = city.indexOf(val) != -1;
                if (check === true){
                    document.getElementById('submit').style.display = "inline-block"
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('submit').style.display = "none"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('submit').style.display = "none";
    addEventListener('click', function () {
    var val = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
    var check = city.indexOf(val) != -1;
    if (check === true){
        document.getElementById('submit').style.display = "inline-block"
    } else {
        document.getElementById('submit').style.display = "none"
    }
}, true);

</script>
```

Comment: Протестировал, консоль выдаёт те значения, которые печатаются. Проблема в самой функции, что то делаю не так
`function checkParams(param) {
    var name = jQuery('#myInput').val(); 
    if(name = this.value(); {  не знаю что тут должно быть
        jQuery('#confirm').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        jQuery('#confirm').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
}
`

Comment: @lancho Только что увидел Ваш код - Вам надо другое событие отслеживать.  Например тык в любое место - могу пример показать. А зачем Вам кстати эта проверка? Получается Вы тоже самое проверяете.

Comment: В смысле тык?) Основная задача это проверять значение города в поле с массивом данных и при его сходстве, активировать кнопку, чтобы посетители не писали всякую ересь вместо города

Comment: @ Denis640Kb, в том то и дело, что если делать проверку строки на сходство со строкой, выходит тоже самое..а мне нужно чтобы проверялся текст из var city

Comment: @lencho так это не сложно. Добавил. Только проверка осуществляется при клике мышки в любом месте после ввода.

Comment: @lencho Если подробнее - то происходит поиск элемента из поля `input` в массиве. Если найден - покажет кнопку.

Comment: спасибо большое! Очень помогли! :) Только учусь основам, пытаюсь изобрести велосипед
Теперь всё работает как надо!

Comment: @lencho Да не за что ))) Добавил новый вариант. Чуть посложнее, но зато теперь кнопка появляется как надо - при выборе города. Попробуйте.

Comment: @ Denis640Kb, протестировал второй вариант. Даже кэш почистил, всё тоже самое..кнопка появляется после клика в случайном месте но не после ввода значения

Comment: Хотя тут всё окей, при выполнении кода

Comment: @lancho Попробуйте ещё раз скопировать, может какую строчку пропустили ))) Проверил ещё раз у себя - работает и при выборе города из списка и при клике мышкой в любом месте. (В случае если полностью город вручную будет прописан).

Comment: @ Denis640Kb, всё дело в `checkParams()`, который я упустил) Теперь всё на 5+

Comment: Спасибо, еще раз! :))